# short circuit protection of mosfet

Tags: mosfet, short-circuit

I am trying to simulate short circuit protection of mosfet.Idea is when current becomes high,voltage across Rsense increases to 0.7v, Hence transistor conduct. Shorting source and gate.But it does not seem to work .Transistor conduct even when resistance is very low.

[image]

Comment: You could test a widely used DESAT circuit for MOSFET/IGBT protection, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Agree with Marko, use the proven desat circuit- e.g. here http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-1014.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The base to collector is forward biased.  The transistor is behaving like a diode.

Comment: After this I am gonna kill myself. Just kidding.Thank you very much.